# Invalid API key Exception Facebook Php Sdk FQL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, exception, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

This code:

```
    $fql2 = "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = xxxxxxxxx)";

$params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'access_token' => $user->accessToken,
    'query' => $fql2,
    'callback'  => ''
);

$result = $facebook->api($params);
var_dump($result);
```

Gives me error: `Uncaught Exception: 101: Invalid API key`

My appId and secret are correct. I have checked it by executing `$facebook->api('/me')` which works perfectly alright. My access token is alright too with all required permissions. There's some problem with the way i'm trying to call the api to execute fql query.

Comment: recheck the `app_id` and `app_secret` that you have supplied to your `$facebook` variable.

Comment: If you've authenticated your user properly, you should not need to pass an `access_token` as part of your `$params`.

Comment: I'm receiving the access_token from another source (a client on mobile) while this script is being run on server end. That's why I have to pass it to the $params array.

Comment: Check the access token using the debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write 

`$user->getAccessToken();`