# FQL query using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have this query:

```
SELECT uid, name, current_location FROM user WHERE uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() ) AND current_location.id IN (Select current_location.id from user where uid = me() )
```

It gives me results as required i-e friends only with a particular location. 
Can i get the same results using Graph API instead? assuming I have the location id. 
I tried this in graph API:

```
me/friends?location.id='111501225536407'&fields=location
```

Is something of ^ sort even possible using graph API?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I can see. The Graph API is best for getting all of or the most recent items of an object. If you wanted to filter those friends by location, you would need to do that on the client side.

If you want Facebook to pre-filter your results on their servers, you need to use FQL.

Comment: Thank you for your response @cpilko 
I could have used fql using Php sdk but for some reason it's not working for me. As i have mentioned in [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205935/invalid-api-key-exception-facebook-php-sdk-fql)

Answer (score 1):

you can execute fql queries (including multiqueries) through the graph api like this:

[https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={"albums":"select aid, name,cover_pid FROM album where owner=me()","album_covers":"select src from photo where pid in (select cover_pid from %23albums)"}&access_token=xxxxxx](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=%7B%22albums%22%3a%22select%20aid,%20name,cover_pid%20FROM%20album%20where%20owner=me%28%29%22,%22album_covers%22%3a%22select%20src%20from%20photo%20where%20pid%20in%20%28select%20cover_pid%20from%20%23albums%29%22%7D&access_token=xxxxxx)

It's a little tricky with the url encoding. Be sure that "#" sign used in multiqueries is encoded as %23